# nMDs non-metric multi-dimensional scaling coding a data set

Tags: r, database

I have a data set of lizard retreat sites that i'd like to examine using an nmds in r to determine which variables are likely important. I'm a novice with r and was told I need to code the data so r can read it. I'm using OS X 10.9.5 (13F1911, r version R 3.3.3 GUI 1.69 Mavericks build (7328).

I'm not sure how to attach the data file, so I've copied the 'head'(data)here:

```
    data <- data.frame(newdataset)
    head(data)


      Hide..  PIT Year                         Species Alive.Partial.Dead         Standing.half.fallen.fallen X..days.obs Total...of.day.occupied Height Diameter Angle Aspect
    1      1 91A1 2004                      Hog Doctor                  A                           S           6                       6    4.2        ?     .      ?
    2      2 91A1 2004                          Mammie                  A                           S           4                       4    1.8   5-10cm    90     SW
    3      3 COFE 2004                Tabebuia riparia                  A                           S          17                      16      3   5-10cm     0    ENE
    4      4 COFE 2004                  Columar cactus                  P                      Fallen           2                       2      0   5-10cm    90      S
    5      5 COFE 2004                               ?                  D                      Fallen           4                       3    0.2   5-10cm    60      ?
    6      6 COFE 2004 Eugenia sp (check greeny fruit)                  P                           S           7                       7    3.5  10-20cm     0      W
```

As you can see I managed to read the data into r, but I'm not sure what is next? I know I need to the convert my data.frame(newdataset) to a distance matrix, but I am unclear if I have to code or create levels for some of the variables, e.g., If the retreat site (selected by the lizard) was in a tree that was either, 1. Alive, 2. Partially Dead, 3. Dead.

A little more about the variables- Column 1. Hide (retreat) Identifies each retreat selected by lizards i.e., one lizard may use a single or multiple retreats, Column 2.Passive Internal Transponder identification number uniquely identifying each lizard, Column 3. Year the data were collected, 4. Species refers to the tree species in which a retreat was located or in the case of a single lizard the substrate (rock) used, 5. Identifies if the tree was alive, partially alive or dead, 6. Identifies if the tree was standing upright, if it was leaning over, or if it was lying on the ground, 7. The number of days a lizard was observed using a particular retreat site, 8. The total number of days a retreat site was known to be used, 9. The height of the retreat site from the ground, 10. The diameter of the section of tree containing the retreat site, 11. The angle of the retreat site relative to the ground, 12. The angle of the retreat site relative to the ground.

Thank you to anyone that can give some advice with this problem.

Cheers
Rick

Comment: Hi! Welcome to Stack Overflow. Next step is to build a distance matrix. You have a lot of variables, so your distance is not going to be one of the most used ones. Do you have an idea of which are the distances used for this kind of data? May be you only want to compute the distance for a few variables of the whole matrix.

Comment: @R18 not sure about the "distance used for this kind of data"? I thought the idea of a nmds was that it could reduce a large # of variables down to a few of the most important ones? Certainly this is what I hope to achieve. I suspect I have to convert the text variables (e.g. tree species) into numbers, but I'm not sure.

Comment: @R18 thanks for improving the formatting of my question.

Comment: Just take a look to the help of `metaMDS` function from `vegan` package (http://cc.oulu.fi/~jarioksa/softhelp/vegan/html/metaMDS.html), what you do with a MDS or NMDS plot is to represent your individuals according to a distance or dissimilarity between them.